# Position fixed acting like position relative ( scrolling with page )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I'm styling an element with position fixed and other css in a certain condition ( basically if the user scrolls up ), but the element is behaving like a relative positioned element. In other words, it is scrolling with the page and not remaining fixed.

I tried isolating this issue, but this issue only exists in this site as a whole and I need it to work in this site.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st<=lastScrollTop){
        //scroll up
        if($(this).scrollTop()>235) $('#searchInput').removeClass('slideIn').addClass('stickySearch');
        else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').addClass('slideIn');
    }
    else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').removeClass('slideIn');
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Right now the class `.slideIn` has no styling associated with it, but `.stickySearch` does.
Here is the CSS:

```
.stickySearch{
    width:56% !important;
    position:fixed !important;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

I checked in developer tools and the class is being applied and the styles are being applied, but the position fixed is just not working.

Here is a live URL: http://goo.gl/ns6UEQ

Note, it helps to have a small window in height so you can scroll. Scroll down so that the header is hidden up top and then scroll up and the search bar should appear, but the moment the header comes back into view the search bar will go back into place in the header.

Comment: `!important` ignores the css if it can be over-written....remove this and you should be gud to go!!

Comment: i think the problem is that you are trying to keep track of the lastscrolltop and test against it, you should only need the inner if/else statement

Comment: @NoobEditor I removed the !important and it still is behaving the same. I of course I had to remove the `position:relative;` originally there so that the fixed would style. So fixed is being styled, but it is still scrolling with the page.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hmmm? No, that is what helps determines if the user is scrolling up. I only want this to happen when the user is scrolling up and the header is hidden.

Comment: @gomangomango, ah, i added an updated answer that will show a modified if statment that will make it so the input will only be fixed when scrolling up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug that exists in CSS and in Chrome and Firefox's implementation of CSS.

When you have a parent element that has `backface-visibility` or is `transformed`, its children can not be fixed.

More here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1129352-CSS3-tip-of-the-week-No-1&highlight=chrome+bug+fixed

Solution: remove the transform and backface visibility styling from `#container`

Answer (score 0):

Change the if statement to something like below

```
var lastScrollTop=0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>150 && lastScrollTop>$(this).scrollTop()){
        $('#fixedinput').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#fixedinput').removeClass('fixed');
    }
    lastScrollTop=$(this).scrollTop();
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4WCpc/5/)

As you scroll down past the grey part the will not be fixed, but once you start scrolling up it will.

Comment: Your JSFiddle works fine, but for some reason `position:fixed;` is not working in my site where I need it to work, that is my problem.

Comment: @gomangomango because the way you currently have your if statement so that the class that sets the position to fixed gets removed when scrolling up more than once. if you scroll up only once it will appear but after subsequent scroll ups it gets removed. you need to change your if statement to work similar to what i have

Comment: Ah, I see. I made your changes, but the problem still exists. The classes are being added fine as with my javascript, but the css is not behaving as it should. Here is a URL with your code from lines 1506 - 1514.